# JMeter - Difference between jexl2 and jexl3

Tags: jmeter, jexl

What is `jexl` and why is it faster performing than `JavaScript` in JMeter?
`${__jexl3("${checkResponse}" != "")}` this code just runs fine in a while controller of Jmeter while the same is not true with `"${checkResponse}" != "" or "${checkResponse}" != "\${checkResponse}"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the differences, see Jexl 3 [changes list](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/changes-report.html#a3.0), e.g.

> Added the range operator (x .. y)

JMeter allow you to choose either version by calling `__jexl2` or `__jexl3` functions

Jexl has more features you can use, for example:

Jexl can also create classes and call methods on them:

```
Systemclass = log.class.forName("java.lang.System");
now = Systemclass.currentTimeMillis();
```